# Not getting the interface updated on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, netplan

Could someone help me to identify what I might be doing wrong? When I'm using the code to generate a ethernet ens38, it is not going through. It doesn't really give me any error when I save the changes to file and then run `sudo netplan apply`, but when checking the interfaces I don't see ens38.

lan-segment.yaml:

[image]

Results of `ip a` :

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 'Bionic Beaver', one of the most popular Ubuntu releases, will reach the end of the standard, five-year maintenance window for Long-Term Support (LTS) releases on 31 May 2023. I recommend that you upgrade to 22.04 LTS. Please edit your question to add the result of: `ip a` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Just added

Comment: @chili555 I am using Ubuntu 10.04 as a part of our lab at college.

Comment: I recommend that you do: `sudo netplan generate` and follow with: `sudo netplan appy` Any errors? Does your netplan file comply with the template at: /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml According to `ip a`, your interface is ens37, not 38. Why do you need ens38 specifically?

Comment: @chili555 That is the code provided by my professor. So the original yaml file is for example: 50-init-cloud.yaml and according to instructions, I should create a copy of this file named lan-segment.yaml where I should be doing the needed modifications, which I did. I was able to modify lan-segment.yaml and save and exit which didn't return any error. After which I have tried sudo netplan apply as well as sudo netplan generate followed by sudo netplan apply as well as sudo reboot but for some reason, the interfaces would not update.